# SharePoint external content type using SharePoint hosted WCF (inside layouts)

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, external-content-type, wcf

I have some requirements to create external content type using WCF service which is hosted into SharePoint layouts folder.

I get error while creating external content type into SharePoint designer using WCF service URL.

[image]

Just curious to know is it possible to create external content type using WCF service which is hosted into SharePoint itself?

I appreciate any inputs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working.

I needed to add serviceBehaviors in my SharePoint web application config file.